# Couldn't catch Firebase Auth

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

i am get this error:  com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException: The given password is invalid. [ Password should be at least 6 characters ]

Couldn't catch Firebase Auth

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.